# read csv file in ansible with no header and no constant data

Tags: ansible

I have below csv file with no constant data. want read each line and create json file using ansible template

```
ABC,1,2,3
EFG,11,12,13,14,15
ZYZ,21,22,23,24,25
```

I am looking for output like below

```
{
            "u_label": "ABC",
            "u_value": "1",
            "c_data": [
                {
                    "u_label": "2",
                    "u_value": "3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "u_label": "EFG",
            "u_value": "11",
            "c_data": [
                {
                    "u_label": "12",
                    "u_value": "13"
                },
                {
                    "u_label": "14",
                    "u_value": "15"
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: There are sites where you can describe a requirement and people, either freely or against money, will write the code for you. SO is not one of them. Please show us what you have tried and explain what is your exact problem when implementing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading above contents using read_csv module as below.

```
- name: test
  read_csv:
    path: /tmp/cis/target_site1.csv
    fieldnames: site,label,dr,no_dr
  register: vms

- debug: msg="{{ vms.list | flatten |list }}"
```

I am not sure how to read null value from below output. if i get null value then i can call it in my jinja template

```
   "msg": [
        {
            "dr": "2",
            "label": "1",
            "no_dr": "3",
            "site": "ABC"
        },
        {
            "dr": "12",
            "label": "11",
            "no_dr": "13",
            "null": [
                "14",
                "15"
            ],
            "site": "EFG"
        },
        {
            "dr": "22",
            "label": "21",
            "no_dr": "23",
            "null": [
                "24",
                "25"
            ],
            "site": "ZYZ"
        }
    ]
}
```